# ApexPages.Message appears as bullet point instead of standard graphic

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I've got a message that I'm adding to a page with the following code:

```
ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, message));
```

The message appears on the resulting page. The expected output is something like this:

[image: Sample Success Message]

Instead, the message is appearing as a bullet point on the resulting page:

[image: ApexPages.Severity as a bullet point]
When looking at the rendered HTML, it is literally rendering it as an HTML bulleted list:

```
<ul role="alert"><li>   Your request for coverage has been submitted. </li></ul>
```

Why would it do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using [`<apex:pageMessages/>`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) in Visualforce?

If you use [`<apex:messages/>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_messages.htm) it will display without formatting.

Hat tip to [@laceysnr](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/78/laceysnr) for [Escaping the Page Messages - Run Away! Inconsistency Alert!](http://www.laceysnr.com/2011/07/escaping-page-messages-run-away.html)

> *On a side note, if you use `<apex:messages/>` you'll find your messages are displayed without formatting, if you use `<apex:pageMessages/>` then they use the default Salesforce styling and look much nicer.

Comment: That totally did it. I was using <apex:messages/> instead of <apex:pageMessages/>. I also realize now that I probably need to not have standardStylesheets="false" in the first <apex> tag, as it appears the default style is set in a standard stylesheet. Now the message appears in the right place but it doesn't quite have the right styling, I'm guessing because of standardStylesheets="false".

Comment: @eyedar that sounds right about `standardStyleSheets="false"` "Note that if you don’t load these style sheets, components that require Salesforce CSS might not display correctly, and their styling may change between releases." [Source](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm)

Comment: Bummer. That means I'm going to have to go through a bunch of hoops just to get the styling right. I had to turn off the standard style sheets because it was interfering with some other elements on the page.